# Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array Clean Code

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop, duplicates, function-definition

> Hello everyone,
> I wrote an code which is remove duplicates from sorted array. I know that there are lots of people have a good know how about clean code in this platform. I want to write code especially clean code. So I wanna hear some suggestion this about. If yo critise my code I am glad.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,8};
    int arr_size = *(&arr + 1) - arr; 

    printf("length of array  %d\n",arr_size);
    int result[arr_size];
    int last_item= result[0];

    for (int i=0; i<arr_size;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]!=last_item)
        {
            last_item= arr[i];
            result[i]= last_item;
            printf("result  : %d\n", result[i]);
        }       
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `last_item= result[0];` I guess in C, there are usually garbage values when nothing is explicitly assigned to them. `arr[i] != last_item`, can be `arr[i] != arr[i-1]` with loop starting from `1` and 0th index taken care of.

Comment: return `0` for sucess
start for loop at 1 and last_item` should be `arr[0]`

Comment: The idiom for getting the length of an array object is `sizeof array / sizeof *array`.

Comment: @Oka You are mistaken. According to the pointer arithmetic you may consider a single object as an array with one element.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Oh, I see that now. This still means "If the
result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated." applies.

Comment: There's https://codereview.stackexchange.com for code review requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters it is unclear why main returns 1 instead of 0.

Secondly you are not removing duplicate elements from an array. You are trying to copy unique elements from one array into another array.
Also it is unclear why the result array has `arr_size` elements as the source array.

This declaration

```
int last_item= result[0];
```

is invalid because the result array is not initialized. So it contains indeterminate values.

Also in the for loop you are using the invalid index `i` for the result array. So again some elements of the result array will have indeterminate values.

```
result[i]= last_item;
```

And within the for loop there should not be any call of `printf`. If you want to output the result array (it is already another task) then you need to use a separate loop or function.

And at last you should write a separate function that performs the task of copying unique or removing duplicate elements..

I would write a function that indeed removes duplicates from an array the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t remove_duplicates( int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t m = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ( i == 0 || a[i] != a[m-1])
        {
            if (i != m)
            {
                a[m] = a[i];
            }
            ++m;
        }
    }

    return m;
}

int main( void )
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,8 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t m = remove_duplicates( arr, N );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 7 8 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: What is the difference between return 1 and return 0 ? Should I initialize the result[0] array? I will consider your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: @Paroz 0 means that the process ended successfully. As for your second question then see the demonstration program in my  answer.